# What impact does the size of SampleCount have on my metrics?

Tags: amazon-web-services, statistics, amazon-cloudwatch

Reading [this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/publishingMetrics.html) and its not clear to me what the impact of sampleCount is on my custom metrics I send as a statistical set.

For example this:

```
aws cloudwatch put-metric-data --metric-name PageViewCount --namespace MyService --statistic-values Sum=11,MinimSampleCountSampleCountum=2,Maximum=5,SampleCount=3 --timestamp 2016-10-14T12:00:00.000Z
```

The SampleCount is 3, but cloudwatch doesn't have the actual points it just has the min,max,sum.

So what if I put 10 for SampleCount or even 10000, what difference does that make?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This CloudWatch metric has several values (minimum, maximum, sum, average, sampleCount, value) that you calculate and use in your own analysis of the published CloudWatch data.

You can set sampleCount to any value that you want but then your average and sum values will not make sense.

In summary, sampleCount is just one of several values that together define the statistics of your system.

This document might help clarify the meaning of each statistic:

[Amazon CloudWatch Concepts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch_concepts.html)

Comment: Still unclear to me. I can set SampleCount to an arbitrary value but what impact does that have on the metric? Seems like I should only ever set it to 2 (one for min and one for max). could it be that if Im consuming cloudwatch metrics with a 3rd party application the application might be able to do something interesting with the samplecount? Because I don't see how cloudwatch uses the SampleCount in any meaningful way

Comment: Let's say you took 10 samples and each was 1.0. The average will be 1.0 and the sum will be 10.0. However, you publish to CloudWatch that you took 3 samples. Now sum / 3 does not equal 1.0 which breaks your Average stat. AWS will calculate the average from the other data points that you provide and use that in their graphs. In this example AWS will calculate 3.33 for the average for that time interval.

Answer (score 4):

Just give you an example here:
If I need to monitor the 400 HTTP access denied error code in my logs group, I would use sample count but not SUM.
Three 400 errors code will result in the number "1200" in the metrics, however sample count will show you the correct number : 3.

Answer (score 0):

Sample Count defines the number of acquired samples it takes in the time window. More samples will have more accurate representation. The min, max and avg are calculated from this subset of samples and not on all samples and this will hence make a difference.

Comment: "More samples will have more accurate representation" yeah but _I'm_ setting that sample count as a value, cloudwatch doesn't actually have those data points. Thats what is confusing to me about this

Comment: Sorry, your answer was not there when I created my answer.